# How do I prevent bash $ substitution?

Tags: linux, bash, unix-shell, sed

I'm trying to preserve $if below and
would like the following to output
    $if

bash is getting in the way by doing
$ substitution

```
$ sed -e 's:\\$:\\$:g' <<ENDOFFILE  
> $if  
> ENDOFFILE
```

or

```
$ tr '$' '\$' <<ENDOFFILE  
> $if  
> ENDOFFILE
```

Is there a way to preserve $keywords
to stdout without explicitly escaping
them out in stdin?

Should I switch to another shell before attempting this?

Comment: Have you tried putting '$if' in single quotes in the text block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but bash is performing parameter expansion in your here document because the delimiter `ENDOFFILE`. If you were to change it to `'ENDOFFILE'` bash would not expand.

Comment: Why does this work and the unquoted ENDOFFILE does not?

Comment: @Dragos: It's [by-design]. If you look in `man bash` you'll see that it's a documented feature.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do here, but you can use tr and the octal value of $ which is 044.  Experiment with this:

echo 'ab$de' | tr \\044 C

Comment: Test your recommendation.  He's trying to escape a variable via STDIN using string manipulation.  You are escaping in the echo.